# Why is intercept value set to 1?

Tags: python, linear-regression, intercept

I am learning the basics of linear regression and how to plot it in Python. In my studying material, I have a data frame containing information on house prices and house sizes. In the material, it says that before feeding this information to the OLS-method in the stats models.api, I have to define a new column called "intercept", where the only value is 1. Why do I have to do this and why does the value of intercept has to be 1? I thought that the value of the intercept is something that is defined later, AFTER the linear regression has been programmed by Python?

Here is my data frame:

```
    price   area
0   598291  1188
1   1744259 3512
2   571669  1134
3   493675  1940
4   1101539 2208
```

And here is the solution offered in my studying material:

```
df['intercept'] = 1
lm = sm.OLS(df.price, df[['intercept', 'area']])
results = lm.fit()
results.summary()
```

Comment: As I recall, OLS will find "weight * predictor" for each term used in the regression. For the intercept, this would be equivalent to "intercept * 1".

Comment: For future readers: This is probably from the worksheet `Housing Analysis` from Udacity.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/396268